# Ruby/Rails - Chain unknown number of method calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to dynamically create (potentially complex) Active Record queries from a 2D array passed into a method as an argument.  In other words, I'd like to take this:

```
arr = [
    ['join', :comments],
    ['where', :author => 'Bob']
]
```

And create the equivalent of this:

```
Articles.join(:comments).where(:author => 'Bob')
```

One way to do this is:

```
Articles.send(*arr[0]).send(*arr[1])
```

But what if `arr` contains 3 nested arrays, or 4, or 5? A very unrefined way would be to do this:

```
case arr.length
    when 1
        Articles.send(*arr[0])
    when 2
        Articles.send(*arr[0]).send(*arr[1])
    when 3
        Articles.send(*arr[0]).send(*arr[1]).send(*arr[2])
    # etc.
end
```

But is there a cleaner, more succinct way (without having to hit the database multiple times)? Perhaps some way to construct a chain of method calls before executing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created following query which will work on any model and associated chained query array.

```
def chain_queries_on(klass, arr)
  arr.inject(klass) do |relation, query|
    begin
      relation.send(query[0], *query[1..-1])
    rescue
      break;
    end
  end
end
```

I tested in local for following test,

```
arr = [['where', {id: [1,2]}], ['where', {first_name: 'Shobiz'}]]

chain_queries_on(Article, arr)
```

Query fired is like below to return proper output,

```
Article Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `article`.* FROM `article` WHERE `article`.`id` IN (1, 2) AND `article`.`first_name` = 'Shobiz'  ORDER BY created_at desc
```

**Note-1:** few noticeable cases

1. for empty `arr`, it will return `class` we passed as first argument in method.
2. It will return `nil` in case of error. Error can occur if we use `pluck` which will return array (output which is not chain-able) or if we do not pass class as first parameter etc.

More modification can be done for improvement in above & avoid edge cases.

**Note-2:** improvements

You can define this method as a class method for `Object` class also with one argument (i.e. array) and call directly on class like,

```
# renamed to make concise
Article.chain_queries(arr)
User.chain_queries(arr)
```

Inside method, use `self` instead of `klass`

Answer (score 2):

One convenient way would be to use a hash instead of a 2D array.

Something like this

```
query = {
  join: [:comments],
  where: {:author => 'Bob'}
}
```

This approach is not much complex and You don't need to worry if the key is not provided or is empty

```
Article.joins(query[:join]).where(query[:where])
#=> "SELECT  `articles`.* FROM `articles` INNER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` WHERE `articles`.`author` = 'Bob'"
```

If the keys are empty or not present at all

```
query = {
  join: []
}

Article.joins(query[:join]).where(query[:where])
#=> "SELECT  `articles`.* FROM `articles`"
```

Or nested

```
query = {
  join: [:comments],
  where: {:author => 'Bob', comments: {author: 'Joe'}}
}
#=> "SELECT  `articles`.* FROM `articles` INNER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` WHERE `articles`.`author` = 'Bob' AND `comments`.`author` = 'Joe'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.inject(Articles){|articles, args| articles.send(*args)}
```